# PHP: search missing dates from date-string

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have s string separated by comma containing a list of dates. This list has been made with mySQL "Group_concat" command and looks like this:

```
11.01.2017, 18.01.2017, 25.01.2017, 01.02.2017, 08.02.2017, 01.03.2017, 08.03.2017
```

The dates have all the same weekdays, e.g. Mondays. Some Mondays are missing in the list, in my example February 15th and 20th 2017.

I'm looking for the missing Mondays of the list and have so far this code:

```
$weekday = 1
//$Kurstage = explode(", ",$rowK->listagg_2 );
$Kurstage = explode(", ","11.01.2017, 18.01.2017, 25.01.2017, 01.02.2017, 08.02.2017, 01.03.2017, 08.03.2017" );
$dateStart = date_create( "11.01.2017");
$dateEnd   = date_create( "08.03.2017");
$missing_dates = array();
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
echo "dateStart:". $dateStart->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ", dateEnd:  " .$dateEnd->format( "Y-m-d" )."<br />";
foreach($period as $day)
{
    if ( $day->format( "w" ) == $weekday )
    {               
        if (! in_array( $day, $Kurstage))
        {
            echo $rowK->code. " - ". $day->format( "Y-m-d" ) ."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

I assume the problem is, that the date in the array created with explode is not recognized as a date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, it's most helpful to explain what went wrong in your example code. Also, you may find date processing work to be easier if you use ISO formatted dates like `2017-01-25` and `2017-02-01` rather than locale-formatted dates as you have shown, And, of course, those example dates are Wednesdays.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have list of Wednesdays instead of Mondays so try this:

```
$weekday = 3;
```

and your second "if" condition is missing date formating

```
// if (! in_array( $day, $Kurstage))
if (! in_array( $day->format( "d.m.Y" ), $Kurstage))
```

Comment: ah this makes a lot of sense now.  thank you so much!

Comment: @ChristophJakob no problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$weekday = 3;
$Kurstage = explode(", ","11.01.2017, 18.01.2017, 25.01.2017, 01.02.2017, 08.02.2017, 01.03.2017, 08.03.2017" );
$dateStart = date_create( "11.01.2017");
$dateEnd   = date_create( "08.03.2017");
$missing_dates = array();
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
echo "dateStart:". $dateStart->format( "Y-m-d" ) . ", dateEnd:  " .$dateEnd->format( "Y-m-d" )."\n";
foreach($period as $day)
{
    if ( $day->format( "w" ) == $weekday )
    {
        if (! in_array( $day->format("d.m.Y"), $Kurstage))
        {
            echo $rowK->code. " - ". $day->format( "Y-m-d" ) ."\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```